# How to pass the reference 'this' to a javascript function from an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I know that this is elementary, but I'm completely unable to pass "this" as a parameter to a JavaScript function.  I'm numb from trying...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ko(control.id){
    alert(control);
}
</script>

<body>
<div id"lala">
    <a id="la" href="javascript:ko(this)" >Votes & Concerns</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The alert tells me "undefined!"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want it to alert("Votes & Concerns")? Anyways, you might start by passing "la" as a string, then getElementByID("la") to get the tag as a DOM object.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Dom hierarchy to discover the IDs of the many DIVs in the screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<a id="la" href="#" onclick="ko(this); return false;" >Votes & Concerns</a>
```

Comment: Your solution is the only one which worked!  Kudos, but mostly thank you.  But please do tell me what the  "return false;" is about???

Comment: I assume that the javascript function returns to the call, but where can the call returns to???  I removed the return false; and it still works!  But I'm a novice...  perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: For events in general if you `return false;` it will prevent the default action of the event from going ahead. With an anchor tag and a click event the default action is to navigate to the specified `href` - in this case ori has set that to "#" so it will stay on the current page but if you don't return `false` the browser will usually scroll back to the top of the current page.

Comment: You rock, @nnnnnn.  Excellent clarity.   Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's the simplest one, though not as educational as the others...

Comment: Actually simplicity is preferred and in this case the only one I got to work.  Thanx @ori

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it from the "href" value, do it from a real event handler attribute:

```
<a id='la' href='#' onclick='ko(event, this)'>
```

Pass in the `event` so that you can prevent the default interpretation of a click on an `<a>` from being undertaken by the browser.

```
function ko(event, element) {
  if ('preventDefault' in event) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false; // for IE

  // here "element" will refer to the clicked-on element ...
}
```

Comment: I get the same result as I was getting originally.  "undefined!"

Comment: Sorry -- I'll extend the answer; this really should work however.

Comment: So, what is the real benefit of doing the 'preventDefault' logic, if already we are doing href='#' ? An answer is much appreciated.

Comment: @united-expression in the case of a "dummy" `<a>` with "#" for the link value, there's not much point. If all you want is an element that can be clicked in order to trigger some JavaScript, then there's really no point using an `<a>` anyway; a `<button>` would probably be better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I just noticed I can do the redirect directly with the anchor, no JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 3):

You've got it the wrong way round:

```
function ko(control){
    alert(control.id);
}
```

`control` is the object (the DOM element object, to be precise) that you're passing with `ko(this)`.  You then want to access its `id` property with `control.id`.

---

NB also that there are much better ways of doing this. The best is to assign the event handlers in Javascript blocks rather than in HTML attributes. For instance:

```
document.getElementById('la').onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Comment: the reason I'm doing this is to get the ID of the outer DIV, actually.  The 'la' id value cannot be known, but by inspection. So I have no use for the "getElementById" command.

Comment: @DennisKean If it's the first `div` in the document, you could use `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onclick = ...` There is almost certainly a solution that allows you to separate JS from HTML.

Comment: It's not really separate if the JS doesn't work without knowing the structure and/or ids of the html.

Comment: I have about 24 complex divs and I fire the anchor from each one of them no knowing which one it is firing.  So discovery is the only way for me...

Comment: No, it's not the only way. It's completely possible to deal with the situation you deal with. But if you don't want to, no skin of my nose...

Comment: I did not mean to brush you off at all @lonesomeday.  Please feel free to add what you wanted to say.  And thank you in any case.